# Ubuntu 22.04 Wine jvm creation error

Tags: wine, java, openjdk

I am trying to install the UNM2000.exe software, from Fiberhome via Wine on Ubuntu 22.04, but I'm getting this wine error:

```
JVM Creation failed.
```

I've used this software with the same installation method over every Ubuntu version since 19.10 and I never had this problem. I haven't found any answer in the Wine or Ubuntu forums.

The installation method is a classic Wine application, an .exe where you give installation permission with `chmod +x` and run .`/UNM2000.exe`. It opens a Next-Next panel, when finished, the application opens and runs normally, but in this Ubuntu version, it installs, but I get this error when trying to open the app.

In order to test different java version, I've used the following commands:

- `sudo apt install default-jre`
- `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless`
- `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless`
- `sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless`
- `sudo apt install openjdk-18-jre-headless`
- `sudo apt install icedtea-netx`

Between the different installations, I did removed the older Java versions using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*
```

I've also tried installing both default-jre and the other commands from the list alongside with each other, but without success.

-sudo apt install default-jre + every item on the previous list

The same error appears on every test, so I believe it is not Java version related, or maybe I did something wrong on the installs.

Anyone knows how to fix something like that on Wine ?
If you need any additional information, please say and I'll supply it.

Picture of the error:

[image: Picture of the error]